# node.js i18n: Use __ or import?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18n-node

I am new to `i18n` and have an existing repository that uses it. I noticed different syntax for using i18n throughout the repository and am wondering what is the best way.

I am confused about the structure below and which syntax option is best (I think it's better to be consistent with the syntax and use only 1 option). Could someone perhaps explain?

In controllers I find:

```
var responses = require('../../locales/en.json');

let message = responses.authorisation.flashes['welcome'];
return res.status(200).json({
  success: true,
  message,
  token,
  user: userData
});
```

In middleware the syntax is as follows:

```
req.flash('error', req.__('organisation.not-found'));
```

And in `app.js` I find:

```
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const flashMiddleware = require('./middleware/flashMiddleware');

const i18n = require('i18n');
i18n.configure({
  locales: [
    'en', 'nl'
  ],
  register: global,
  directory: path.join(__dirname, 'locales'),
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  objectNotation: true,
  updateFiles: false
});
```

`flashMiddleware.js` contains (I'm not sure what this does):

```
const flashMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();

  next();
};

module.exports = flashMiddleware;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your first and last code blocks don't appear to be using `i18n` at all. Instead, the first code block is loading the JSON for `en` and using it directly. It's not clear what the flash stuff is using, I don't see anything in that code doing localization.

The middleware syntax, using `__` on `req`, appears to be the standard way you use this library in middleware.

There are other ways to use it as well that are detailed in [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n).

Comment: Thanks, I've added the i18n code that is in app.js in the OP. I think that does the localization (it might also not be completely set up for internationalisation, since at the moment the site is in only 1 language). Is there a difference, for example in performance or otherwise, between the two syntaxes? I mean wouldn't it make sense to also use the `__` syntax in the controller? (for consistency)

Comment: @Marty - I think it does, and not just for consistency. Presumably at some point the app will be in more than one language (otherwise, why use localization files and `i18n` at all?). The controller code assumes English, so if/when you go to multiple languages, you have to edit the controller code to match the middleware code anyway. Might as well set out as you mean to go on... :-) (I realize the code is already there, so "set out" isn't really accurate, but...)